# Header Access-Control-Allow-Origin for static file in Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail, and I need to have a static file inside my public directory to be served with the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'.

But I don't know how to add this header in Laravel Sail since it does not use neither nginx nor apache (but php artisan serve). Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Oof! Great question! In which way do you want to serve that file? Maybe a controller in Laravel? Or just point directly to that file? When you point directly to that file, there's no way to add extra headers

Comment: I need to serve it directly. thanks.

Comment: So ... in the server world you either have an apache or an nginx server that serves your pages. With nginx you'll have a `location` block. If the location is `/my-spcial-file` you can send extra headers. Google for `nginx location block example` and I hope it gives you a great example